# Determining if a state-space realization is minimal.

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

Is it true that the state-space realization above is minimal if and only if there exists a real $\alpha$ for which the following two matrix equations have symmetric and positive definite solutions **P** and **W**? Prove or give counter example.

$A^{T}P + PA + \alpha P= -BB^{T}$

$AW + WA^{T} + \alpha W= -C^{T}C$

I know that a system is minimal if and only if it is controllable and observable. My first instinct was to use the PBH test for controllability and observability but the form of the equations does not lend itself to that test. Thoughts?

Comment: Think Grammians & Lyapunov equations and write the equations as $(A+{\alpha \over 2})^T + P (A+{\alpha \over 2}) + BB^T=0$, etc, and choose $\alpha$ such that the resulting matrix is Hurwitz.

Comment: Note that $(A,B)$ is cc. **iff** $(A-\lambda I ,B)$ is cc. for any $\lambda$.

Comment: cc. = completely controllable.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @copper.hat Suppose (A,B) is cc. Then By the controllability Gramian we know $BB^{T}$ is positive definite **iff** all eigenvalues of A have negative real parts. Let P = $\int_0^\infty e^{(A+\alpha/2)^{T}t}BB^{T}e^{(A+\alpha/2)t}$_dt_ so the left side factors and reduces to $e^{(A+\alpha/2)^{T}t}BB^{T}e^{(A+\alpha/2)t}$ evaluated at $t=0$  and $\infty$. Then select $\alpha$ such that eigenvalues of A have negative real parts. Then the exponential goes to $0$ and the LHS reduces to the RHS.

Comment: @copper.hat I feel like my proof is missing something? Also I am not sure how to prove the statement going back the other way.

Comment: The $\implies$ direction is straightforward, because we can make $A$ Hurwitz. I am stuck on the reverse direction.

Comment: The best I can manage is that the system is minimal **iff** there exists some $\alpha_0$ such that for all $ \alpha \ge \alpha_0$ the following...